# Why is a string in another string split in bash/ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh

I learned how to use ssh by the following format,

```
ssh "${address}" "command run in a remote server"
```

So I made a following code,

```
# script name : test.sh
address='127.0.0.1'
file="test.txt"
pattern='Number of records'
ssh "${address}" "grep "${pattern}" "${file}""
```

The output of 'bash -x test.sh' is following,

```
 ssh 127.0.0.1 'grep Number' of 'records test.txt'
 grep: of: No such file or directory
 grep: records: No such file or directory
 grep: test.txt: No such file or directory
```

It seems that "grep "${pattern}" "${file}"" is interpreted as following 3 strings

```
 (grep Number)  + (of) + (records test.txt)
```

Why are the strings split like that? And what is the solution? Please tell me them. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash would substitute variables, and treat it as unquoted. Second, you can not use quotes within quotes without escaped. Note this command

```
"grep "${pattern}" "${file}""
```

would be transformed to (the second quote would be treated as the end of string):

```
"grep "Number of records" "test.txt""
```

and then the strings not delimited by white spaces would be concatenated to one( the spaces inside quotes are not delimiters). Thus we got

```
(grep Number) (of) (records test.txt)
```

To solve this, escape the inside quotes or just use another kind of quote

```
ssh "${address}" "grep \"${pattern}\" ${file}"
```

or

```
ssh "${address}" "grep '${pattern}' ${file}"
```

I think `${file}` should not be quoted for it should be treated as separated arguments if it contains multiple files.

Comment: thank you for telling detailed mechanism. It is very clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Unescaped quotes don't nest.

```
ssh "${address}" "grep \"${pattern}\" \"${file}\""
```